# No autocompletion on object conforming to internal protocol inherited from public protocol

Tags: swift, swift4.2

What effective access level will have a property declared in public protocol and implemented as public in the extension of internal protocol that was inherited from that public protocol?

I have this simplified declaration in a framework:

```swift
public protocol PublicProtocol: AnyObject {
    var visible: Int { get }
    func test()
}

protocol InternalProtocol: PublicProtocol {
    var invisible: Int { get }
}

extension InternalProtocol {
    public var visible: Int { return 4 }
    var invisible: Int { return 8 }

    public func test() {
        print("visible: \(self.visible), invisible: \(self.invisible)")
    }
}

public class Object: InternalProtocol {
    public init () {}
}
```

After importing that framework into the main module, the following code compiles and runs just fine:

```swift
let o = Object()
o.test() // prints "visible: 4, invisible: 8"
```

Xcode's compilation and syntax highlighting works as expected, but there is no code completion at all:

[image: Strange, isn't it?]

Is it an Xcode-specific bug, or I'm doing something wrong? If it's a bug, than what exactly causes it: it's a Swift allowing a public class to adopt an internal protocol inherited from public protocol, or it's just an Xcode's code autocompletion got stuck trying to calculate an `Object`'s public interface?

Xcode 10.1 (10B61).